# Is it possible for webpage to dynamically insert data from another file without needing a server call

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible for webpage to dynamically insert data from another file without needing a server call?

What I mean by that is can a .html page update itself with something like XMLHttpRequest but instead of this making a call to a server just simply read in a file that is the same location as the html page.

Pseudocode

```
if(userclicks on x)
{
    read and display contents of y within this div)
}
```

**Background**

I am converting an html report that currently uses a *frameset* divided into left and right panels. The left panel lists a series of folders that have been processed, the right-hand side shows the processing done on the selected folder.

1. I need to remove framset because outdated and not supported in html 5
2. iFrames not a suitable alternative as they are not designed for showing the content of an integral part of the site, they look plain weird when this is done.
3. It is not viable to preload all the content of the page and then uses javascript to hide/show the content of the file when user changes selection because the single html file would be too large and too slow to load.
4. It is not viable to make a call to a server because there is no server, the reports are created by an application and then can be viewed standalone without the application being run. They can also be sent to support to be viewed standalone.
5. My temporary solution is that when the user selects a file then the processing html file is displayed in a new tab (or window), but there is not a very satisfactory for the user

Comment: I could be misreading your question, but it sounds like what you want is technically a server call. Anything that hosts the file you want to get the contents from is its server.

Comment: @ACJ There is no server (except file server), i.e I can use Open File in webbrowser to show the report, there is no instance of Apache Server, Tomcat etc running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your question right, all of the necessary **data** is part of the page at the outset (since you can't load it from a server, it **has** to all already be there — but see under the line below for more on that). But you've said:

> It is not viable to preload all the content of the page and then uses javascript to hide/show the content of the file when user changes selection because the single html file would be too large and too slow to load.

So that suggests the data itself is quite a bit smaller than the representation of the data.

You can certainly have an element on the page (for instance, a `div`) that you update with a rendering of a subset of the data the page holds, using the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model). Here's a trivial example:

```js
const data = [
    {label: "one", a: "a one", b: "b one", c: "c one"},
    {label: "two", a: "a two", b: "b two", c: "c two"},
    {label: "three", a: "a three", b: "b three", c: "c three"},
    {label: "four", a: "a four", b: "b four", c: "c four"}
];

function populateMenu() {
    const menu = document.getElementById("menu");
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
      const entry = data[i];
      const a = document.createElement("a");
      a.href = `#entry-${i}`;
      a.textContent = entry.label;
      a.addEventListener("click", event => {
          event.preventDefault();
          showEntry(entry);
      });
      menu.appendChild(a)
    }
}

function showEntry(entry) {
    const content = document.getElementById("content");
    const {a, b, c} = entry;
    content.textContent = `a: ${a}, b: ${b}, c: ${c}`;
}

populateMenu();
```

```css
#menu a {
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

That uses ES2015+ syntax, but you can do the same thing with ES5 only if you need to for your target environments.

The `content` div there can, of course, be the majority of the page display.

This is the basic nature of a *single-page application* (SPA), so further research using that term may be useful. But your SPA is standalone (whereas most will do server calls, but still update the page as above).

---

In a comment you've said:

> Currently the files are created at the outset, there is the main folder and a file that represents the processing of each folder. The user could have processed a 1000 folders so that means the main file is essentially a list of 1000 folders, and then there are a 1000 other files each containing a few pages of data. SO clearly if we to combine of all of this into one file it would be about 1000 time larger, yet user would only eve be viewing the procesing associated with one folder...So your approach above would not work for me.

I'm afraid you're trying to have your cake and eat it. :-) Either you can load the data later, or it's all on the page at the outset. You said in the question you can't load the data later, so it must be in the page at the outset.

**But**: Your use of the word "files" above suggests that this report without a server can be a *set* of files, not just a single file.

Your cross-browser options if HTML File A needs to load content from HTML File B are:

- Use `iframe`s and update the `src` to go from file to file. You've said in the question that they "aren't for the main content of the page", but that's not my understanding; and that they're ugly, but they're **completely** stylable via CSS. They can literally be seamlessly integrated into the main page.
- Keep using frames, update the `src` of the frame to move from file to file. Yes, `frames` were removed in HTML5. They will never be removed from web browsers, too much legacy.

Sadly, you can't reliably use `XMLHttpRequest` when your page is loaded from a `file:` URL. Some browsers allow it, others don't. (You can't use `fetch` in any of them, it specifically doesn't support the `file:` scheme.)

Your constraints literally constrain your choices, I'm afraid.

Here's an `iframe` example:

`report.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<title>Report</title>
<style>
#menu a {
    padding: 4px;
}
#content {
    border: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="menu">
    <a href="#file-1" data-file="file1.html">File 1</a>
    <a href="#file-2" data-file="file2.html">File 2</a>
    <a href="#file-3" data-file="file3.html">File 3</a>
</div>
<iframe id="content" src="file1.html"></iframe>
<script>
document.getElementById("menu").addEventListener("click", event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const a = event.target.closest("a");
    document.getElementById("content").src = a.getAttribute("data-file");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`file1.html` (`file2.html` and `file3.html` are identical, just different names and numbers):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<title>File 1</title>
</head>
<body>
This is file 1.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Currently the files are created at the outset, there is the main folder and a file that represents the processing of each folder. The user could have processed a 1000 folders so that means the main file is essentially a list of 1000 folders, and then there are a 1000 other files each containing a few pages of data. SO clearly if we to combine of all of this into one file it would be about 1000 time larger, yet user would only eve be viewing the procesing associated with one folder,

Comment: @PaulTaylor - I'm afraid you're trying to have your cake and eat it. :-) Either you can load the data later, or it's all on the page at the outset. You said in the question you can't load the data later, so it must be in the page at the outset.

Comment: I've added to the end of the answer above with more detail.

Comment: I didnt say I cant load the data later I said there is no server, is there not just a way  can  simply just read from a file rather than taking to a server

Comment: Read your updated answer, perhaps I can use iframes then ? - I have never actually used them it was simply my understanding from what I have read, I thought they always came with a border.

Comment: @PaulTaylor - I'd probably use iframes, yes. Or, frankly, frames. They're not "cool" but needs must. :-)

Comment: @PaulTaylor FWIW, I've added an `iframe` example. Happy coding!

Comment: Thx useful answer, but I have gone with another answer using XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Hmm, I tested it with my report and it worked and that is with opening the report as a file url and there is no server running. However I tested with Firefox, works fine, then tested with Safari works fine, then tested with Chrome doesnt work :(

Comment: @PaulTaylor - Right -- that's what I warned about in the answer above. :-) It basically only works in Firefox (and that may change, the general shift is that ajax should always fail on `file:` URLs -- `fetch` always does, for instance). (Well, I don't know about Edge or IE, but...)

Comment: I know, I asked the question and the poster said it worked with Chrome, my assumption was that it just didnt work with some old browsers and that would not be a problem. But like I said there is no server actually running, so it could work.

Comment: Hi, I managed to get iFrame version working but my problem compared with the other one is that the iFrame has a small size vertically/horizontally despite me using Bootstrap Grid and the div col that the iframe is in having 80% of the width and non limit on height, how can I fix that ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor - That's a CSS issue which is really a separate question, I suggest putting together an MCVE and posting a question asking about that (but there's probably already a question about it here, so you might find it in a search). But don't worry, it's totally doable to make the iframe fit the size of its parent page.

Comment: Sure thing, okay I have got it roughly working by setting style on iframe as  style="border:none; width:100%;height:500px" - that will do for now. Okay I will mark your answer as correct

Answer (score 1):

## [`<template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template)

If you have local content on a file try using an `<iframe>` or a `<template>`. The latter is what we will consider. A `<template>` is inert and ignored by the browser so no matter how huge your extra content is -- it shouldn't be an issue.

### Demo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page 1</title>
  <style>
    html {
      font: 400 16px/1.5 'Consolas';
      background: #000;
      color: #fc0;
    }
    
    fieldset {
      border-color: goldenrod;
      border-radius: 8px;
    }
    
    input,
    output {
      display: block;
      font: inherit;
    }
    
    [type=submit] {
      float: right;
      background: none;
      color: gold;
      border: 1px solid gold;
      border-radius: 4px;
      margin-top: 4px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form id='import'>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Import data.html by <b>XMLHttpRequest()</b></legend>
      <output id='content'></output>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>

  <template id='data'>
<style>{margin: 30px auto}table{table-layout: fixed;border: 3px solid cyan;width: 99%;border-radius: 6px}caption{font-size:1.2rem;color:gold}th{width: 33%;background: rgba(0,11,187,0.3);border: 1px solid rgba(0,11,187,0.7);color:#fc3}td{min-height: 30px;border: 2px ridge cornflowerblue;;color: yellow;background: none}
</style><section><table><caption>DATA</caption><thead><tr><th>TH</th><th>TH</th><th>TH</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>TD</td><td>TD</td><td>TD</td></tr><tr><td>TD</td><td>TD</td><td>TD</td></tr><tr><td>TD</td><td>TD</td><td>TD</td></tr></tbody></table></section>
</template>
  <script>
    document.forms.import.onsubmit = getContent;

    function getContent(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const destination = document.querySelector('#content');
      const template = document.querySelector('#data');
      const clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
      destination.appendChild(clone);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

## [XMLHttpRequest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Assuming that a separate web page on the same domain as the target web page is feasible it is possible to import HTML from another webpage (whether from a server or same domain) using XMLHttpRequest().

#### Demo Outline

- Main page: **index.html**, Imported page: **data.html**
- On main page the element that will have the imported HTML needs this:

  > ```
  >   <div data-x="data.html"...
  > ```

  Any type of element assigned `data-x` attribute with the value of the imported web page's URL.

---

## [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/KG46Pni4g1kpI1Pe)

### index.html

**This Stack Snippet does not function because it loads an external page, for a working demo review this [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/KG46Pni4g1kpI1Pe)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page 1</title>
  <style>
    html {
      font: 400 16px/1.5 'Consolas';
      background: #000;
      color: #fc0;
    }
    
    fieldset {
      border-color: goldenrod;
      border-radius: 8px;
    }
    
    input,
    output {
      display: block;
      font: inherit;
    }
    
    [type=submit] {
      float: right;
      background: none;
      color: gold;
      border: 1px solid gold;
      border-radius: 4px;
      margin-top: 4px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form id='import'>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Import data.html by <b>XMLHttpRequest()</b></legend>
      <output data-x="data.html"></output>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>

  <script>
    function xhr(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const tags = document.querySelectorAll("*");
      let clone, file, xh;
      for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        if (tags[i].dataset.x) {
          clone = tags[i].cloneNode(false);
          file = tags[i].dataset.x;
          xh = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xh.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xh.readyState == 4 && xh.status == 200) {
              clone.innerHTML = xh.responseText;
              tags[i].parentNode.replaceChild(clone, tags[i]);
              xhr();
            }
          };
          xh.open("GET", file, true);
          xh.send();
          return;
        }
      }
    }
    document.forms.import.addEventListener('submit', xhr);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

### data.html

**This is just the plain web page that is imported to index.html, for a working demo, review this [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/KG46Pni4g1kpI1Pe)**

```html
<style>
  section {
    margin: 30px auto;
  }
  
  table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    border: 3px solid cyan;
    width: 99%;
    border-radius: 6px;
  }
  caption {
    font-size:1.2rem;
    color:gold;
  }
  th {
    width: 33%;
    background: rgba(0,11,187,0.3);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,11,187,0.7);
    color:#fc3;
  }
  
  td {
    min-height: 30px;
    border: 2px ridge cornflowerblue;;
    color: yellow;
    background: none;
  }
</style>
<section>
  <table>
    <caption>DATA</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>TH</th>
        <th>TH</th>
        <th>TH</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>TD</td>
        <td>TD</td>
        <td>TD</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TD</td>
        <td>TD</td>
        <td>TD</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TD</td>
        <td>TD</td>
        <td>TD</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</section>
```

Comment: Thankyou, so the key part is this part - xh.open("GET", file, true);xh.send(); I wil give this a go

Comment: The other answer says - 'Sadly, you can't reliably use XMLHttpRequest when your page is loaded from a file: URL. Some browsers allow it, others don't' -  would youknow if this is still an issue with modern browsers ?

Comment: All I know is I have similar code in production for the last 3 years and never had a problem. But my clients are required to use Chrome, Firefox, or Safari so I cannot say if IE10 or Edge will support it.

Comment: thanks did some test and it works for me, I will mark your answer correct but i didnt need to use data-x and the key thing is the xdr code and this is not visible in your answer only the working example perhaps you could modify your answer to make it clearer.

Comment: You're welcome, the `xhr()` function is at the bottom of the Snippet -- it's the whole page I didn't use all 3 edit boxes just the HTML box.

Comment: The OP specifically said in the question *"...like XMLHttpRequest but instead of this making a call to a server just simply read in a file..."* and *"It is not viable to make a call to a server because there is no server,"* You can't use `XMLHttpRequest` cross-browser without making a call to a server. It doesn't work with `file:` URLs in multiple browsers (Chrome, for instance).

Comment: It worked with Firefox and Safari, but tried with Google ( 72.0.3626.121 on Windows) and that doesnt work :(

Comment: Re template: The OP **also** specifically said all the text/markup cannot be in one file. Having it hidden and then revealed was listed and rejected as an option.

Comment: Yep, concur. I would leave your XMLHttpRequest answer as it is useful and so nearly worked, but my query is with Chrome. Is this just an oversight on your part does own production code work with Chrome or not, did you devise a workaround ?

Comment: No, I forgot the specifics concerning your situation. I updated the answer with a new solution that involves a `<template>`. The markup can be huge and loading time isn't hindered because `<template>`s are inert and ignored by browsers.

Comment: The file still has to be read by browser but even if you are correct there are still problem with the report code generator all writing to one file because could not then multithread. Thanks for your help but I have decided to go with iframes instead

Comment: Of course no problem, iframes would've been my first choice but the OP mentioned it wasn't feasible.